# avoid exponential from double in gwt

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

How can I remove exponent from double at client side in gwt.

```
public double evaluate(final double leftOperand, final double rightOperand) {
        Double rtnValue = new Double(leftOperand * rightOperand);
            //Require to write code which remove exponent before return
        return rtnValue.doubleValue();
    }
```

Server side possible using NumberFormat

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
        System.out.println(number);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(number));
```

But client side it throw exception like:
16:08:04.190 [ERROR] [vflow] Line 359: No source code is available for type **java.text.NumberFormat**; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Because gwt does not include lib java.text  [JRE Emulation Reference](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation)

And Also I tried with **String.format("%.2f", doubleResult);**

is String.format() not supported in GWT, or am i doing something wrong 
here?

So how can I avoid exponential from double? is there any ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using javascript with JSNI:

```
native String format(double num) /*-{

  // ...implemented with JavaScript
  var v = num;
  return "" + v.valueOf();

}-*/;
```

I don't have the GWT sdk with me right now to try it, but it should be something like this.

Comment: When I call this method it is throwing error:                                                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Something other than a Java object was returned from JSNI method '@com.client.test.ExponentTest::format(D)': JS value of type int, expected java.lang.Object

Comment: =\ try change the return value of "format" to int or Object and see what happen

Comment: Thank u very much.It is done. I have return with return ""+ v.valueOf();.

Answer (score 0):

There is a custom NumberFormat available in GWT:
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/NumberFormat.html

GWT doesn't support the Java API for NumberFormat and DateFormat because of compatibility reasons. This is described on this page: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsFormatting